# Problem running the script in .sh file

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to execute below script

```
rm -rf /home/apps/temp
export DAA_HOME=/home/apps/Tools/3.6/eclipse
export BuildFile=/home/apps/Tools/Automated/BuildFile
alias Studio_Home=$DAA_HOME
rm -f Studio_Home/build.xml
cp $BuildFile/build.xml Studio_Home
cd Studio_Home
ant -f build.xml
```

And I'm getting following errors:

```
cp: cannot stat ‘/home/apps/Tools/Automated/BuildFile\r/build.xml’: No such file or directory
: No such file or directoryudio_Home
```

Can anyone please help??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux told you about your problem just fine, you just have to read:

> /home/apps/Tools/Automated/BuildFile\r/build.xml: No such file or directory

There's a little `\r` which shouldn't be there. It seems like, in your script, the `\r` character was inserted at the end of the following line:

```
export BuildFile=/home/apps/Tools/Automated/BuildFile
```

Make sure your script file is saved in UTF-8 for UNIX. Lines ending with `\r\n` are typical to DOS systems like Windows. In `gedit`, this parameter can be set in the *Save As* window.

[image: Gedit Save As]

As a command line solution, here's a little `sed` replacement line:

```
sed "s/\r\n/\n/g" -i ./script.sh
```

You could also use the `dos2unix` program:

```
sudo apt-get install dos2unix
dos2unix ./script.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

You have carriage return character in the path:

`/home/apps/Tools/Automated/BuildFile\r/build.xml`

It is invisible, that's why you didn't notice it. The simplest solution is to just re write this fragment by hand again in your editor and save the file.